# How to wait for ALL child processes to terminate and get each exit status

Tags: c, process, exit, wait

So I've done a bit of research but not a lot of it seems to fit my situation or I'm just not understanding it.

I basically have a parent process that forks - it makes a child.. now this child will also fork at some point.

I want the parent process.. the main parent to be able to catch the exit status of ANY children (the child of the first fork and ANY of its children when it forks)

I basically have any process exit if something goes wrong.. and I want the main parent to receive this exit status.. and if it exited because of an error i can catch it with like an if statement and print something out.

Currently.. I can catch if the first child exits with and error and get the right exitstatus.. but any of its children it wont work. Not sure if I have to use a weird version of waitpid or what.

How do I do this?

Comment: im sorry. im writing my own mini-shell... that should operate like unix.

Comment: Waiting on grandchildren or other non-direct-children processes is impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [wait](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) system call (or `waitpid(-1, &status, 0)`). Or wait on some process group ID (since all your indirect children share the same process group, unless they change it.). Perhaps create your own process group with [setpgid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setpgid)

And you get the SIGCHLD [signal](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal) when a child exits.

Comment: I want to check all of them also.. as in.. if one exits fine.. I want to know that.. and if the next one doesnt.. I want to know that also.

would I need a while statement or something to continue looping?

Comment: If you are writing your small shell, did you consider studying the source code of an existing one, like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell

Comment: On Linux, you can also use `strace` to understand the system calls involved on a program (like e.g. some existing shell).